# How to create frequency vector on a rating scale

Tags: r, tabular

I have a vector that contains values from 1 to 5:

```
c(4,5,5,5,1)
```

I need to get the frequency of the values expressed in a vector according to a rating scale of 1 to 5.

```
Scale: 1 2 3 4 5
Frequ: 1 0 0 1 3
```

So I try to achieve the following sequence:

```
c(1,0,0,1,3)
```

Does anybody now how to to this in R? I tried to use `table` and `as.data.frame` but I could not create that vector out of it. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect example of where you can use a factor.

```
## Create example data
d = c(4,5,5,5,1)
## Specify the appropriate
d_fac = factor(d, levels = 1:5)
```

Then use `table` as usal

```
table(d_fac)
# d_fac
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 1 0 0 1 3
```